# Custom processor and backpressuring, throttling

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi 1.2.0

There is a custom processor that reads data from db and passes it further. In a recent stress testing, the 'success' relationship queue was clogged and also the later flow as the processor dumped hundred thousands of flow files of several GBs. Obviously, the [backpressuring](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/getting-started.html#connecting-processors)  was not implemented. I also read an informative [post](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/kbentry/9785/nifihdf-dataflow-optimization-part-2-of-2.html) about throttling and backpressuring.

What I have figured out is that backpressuring is something we configure in the relationship queue and standard processors like ControlRate can help to regulate the data flow.

Question :

Is additional coding required(e.g: Some interface to be implemented) in the processor to enable it to 'sleep/stop consuming data' for backpressuring or does the NiFi framework handle that, once the 'success' relationship of  the processor is configured for backpressuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No additional coding is required.  The NiFi framework manages backpressure for you and will stop calling your processor when backpressure is applied.

Comment: That is what even I think. Can I assume that backpressuring/throttling means just configuring the relationship(Back Pressure Object Threshold, FlowFile Expiration, Back Pressure Data Size Threshold) and, if required, add processors like ControlRate ?